# Flask destructor

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a web application using Flask. I've sub-classed the Flask object so that I can execute a chunk of code before the app exits (the Flask object get's destroyed). When I run this in my terminal and hit ^C, I'm not seeing the *"Can you hear me?"* message, so I assume that `__del__()` isn't getting called.

```
from flask import Flask

class MyFlask (Flask):

  def __init__(self, import_name, static_path=None, static_url_path=None,
                     static_folder='static', template_folder='templates',
                     instance_path=None, instance_relative_config=False):

    Flask.__init__(self, import_name, static_path, static_url_path,
                         static_folder, template_folder,
                         instance_path, instance_relative_config)

    # Do some stuff ... 

  def __del__(self):
    # Do some stuff ... 
    print 'Can you hear me?'

app = MyFlask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
 return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

I'd like this code to execute in the destructor so that it'll run no matter how the application is loaded. i.e, `app.run()` in testing, `gunicorn hello.py` in production. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use [signals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) in your script to catch the program ending.

Comment: Good idea. It's easy enough to catch SIGINT, but I need to do some research on what signals will be used when the code is deployed. This is going to be put on Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) Also, `__del__()` methods may not have access to global variables, since those may already have been deleted. Relying on destructors in Python is a bad idea.

Comment: The code would only reference the instance itself, no globals.

Comment: @Chris: It calls `Flask.__del__`. `Flask` is a global.

Comment: Aw yes, I see. But if this were omitted, how could it be that the destructor doesn't get called? Is something else referencing `app` to the very last second?

Comment: @Chris: The `app` variable still exists when your script ends.

Comment: Of course it does, but its reference count should drop to 0 after ^C is typed. My guess is that it's a WSGI thing.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is possible:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()  #or what you need
    try:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
    finally:
        # your "destruction" code
        print 'Can you hear me?'
```

I have, however, no clue if you can still use `app` in the finally block ...

Comment: This is the best solution, and yes, you can still fully use the app object in the finally block.